# Access update statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to make all the dates from a column null except for 10/15/2012 in access here what I have so far.

```
Update tbl_ReleaseTracking Set 2nd_Ltr_Sent= null WHERE  2nd_Ltr_Sent <> #10/15/2012#
```

I get the error missing operator in query expression '2nd_LRT_Sent <> #10/15/2012#.

Comment: Are you trying to make the field null or delete the data rows?  Your description say delete, but your SQL looks like it's updating the field to null

Comment: Null I'll update the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I'm not familiar with MS Access, I think that columns should not start with a number. Tried enclosing the column name with ``?

Comment: Thanks that will be the first thing I try when I get into work tommorow.

Comment: It is more usual to use square brackets [] with MS Access.

Comment: @Remou is correct and `` will not work in MS Access. You will be asked to Enter Parameter Value '2nd_Ltr_Sent' in Access 2007.

Comment: Weird I tried it both ways and it worked with '' around the columns

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
Update tbl_ReleaseTracking Set [2nd_Ltr_Sent]= null 
WHERE [2nd_Ltr_Sent] <> #10/15/2012#
```